# Logic App Custom Connector SOAP to Rest problem

Tags: azure, soap, wsdl, azure-logic-apps

When I try to create a connector in Logic App Custom Connector, with endpoint SOAP to Rest, i'm getting the following error:

The provided WSDL import method'NotSpecified' is not valid. The supported import methods are 'SoapToRest, SoapPassThrough'.

I already has done this before, and worked, but now, I cant do anymore.

Anyone knows what is happening?

Thank you

Comment: See if this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-api-import-restrictions#a-namewsdl-awsdl) helps?

Comment: @JoyWang I think not, because last week I made the import of the same WSDL without changes, and now it's impossible for me doing again.

Comment: For such type issue, I recommend you to [contact azure support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).